# 64 bit ArcPy works on server but not through Citrix, path looks fine, what is going on? (ArcGIS Desktop 10.3)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, 64bit

I can import ArcPy fine if I'm on the server itself; but If I access ArcGIS through Citrix using the same server I can't import it. I checked the paths and they look identical, I don't see anything missing.
[image]

I noticed that on the actual server, there is no Python path; while on the Citrix applicaiton, the path is pointing to regular 32 bit

```py
>>> print os.environ['PYTHONPATH']

c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\bin;c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcPy;c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts
```

This area is not my area of expertise, but I am guessing that the Python path needs to change for the Citrix application?

Comment: Ya, its crossing the bits. Your citrix environment probably has some special loading to enable/set Desktop specific settings. From your screen shot, it has a very confused Python path pointing to both installations. I have no idea how to "fix" your citrix environment, but your error and screen shot all make sense as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Cool, thanks; came here first because my organization is huge and slow so I was hoping I could fix this myself. Guess I'll have to submit a ticket and wait